# SDL_Renderer won't show textures after passing through the function

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl-2, renderer

I have a little problem with SDL_Renderer. I can't understand why it doesn't work. Let's look at this example, it works fine:

```
bool running = true;
SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("ASDF", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
SDL_Texture* texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "asdf.bmp");
SDL_Event event;

while(running)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                {
                    running = false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
```

Then it comes to classes and when I pass the renderer through functions, it won't work anymore.

```
class Sprite
{
public:
    Sprite(const std::string& path) : filePath(path) {};
    ~Sprite() { SDL_DestroyTexture(tex); };
    void draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer);

private:
    const std::string& filePath;
    SDL_Texture* tex;
};

void Sprite::draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    printf("renderer sprite = %p\n", renderer);

    tex = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, filePath.c_str());
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tex, NULL, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    bool running = true;
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("ASDF", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_Event event;

    Sprite* sprite = new Sprite("asdf.bmp");
    while(running)
    {
        printf("renderer main = %p\n", renderer);

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
                case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                    {
                        running = false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        sprite->draw(renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The address of renderer is the same in main and in the draw function. I know that I'm probably making some sort of beginner's mistake here but i can't find it out.

Comment: Not sure if it is the cause but you are loading the texture over and over with every call to `sprite->draw`. You should do it once in the constructor or a function to load media. It may be that the image is not ready to be rendered since it has only just been loaded.

Comment: OK, I'll put it as an answer then

Answer (score 1):

The texture is being loaded every frame when you call `sprite->draw`.

You should move the line `tex = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, filePath.c_str());` to the constructor so that it is only loaded once.

The reason for this is that the texture will not be ready for rendering in the same frame that it is loaded.

As a side note you don't appear to be cleaning up the `SDL_Window` or `SDL_Renderer` with their respective destroy functions or calling `SDL_Quit` although I accept this may have been omitted for submitting the code example.