# SDL_Renderer: OpenGL texture just won't stick

Tags: opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using the SDL_Renderer API to draw a (mostly) 2D scene, but struggling to bind and apply a texture to 3D geometry with it. I've tried binding the texture using OpenGL calls directly, and I've also tried creating my texture with `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`, and binding with `SDL_GL_BindTexture`. In both cases, I'm left with flat white geometry. Here's the code in question:

```
/**
 * @see View::render(View *, SDL_Renderer *)
 */
static void render(View *self, SDL_Renderer *renderer) {

    super(View, self, render, renderer);

    MeshModelView *this = (MeshModelView *) self;

    if (this->model) {

        const SDL_Rect frame = $(self, renderFrame);
        glViewport(frame.x, frame.y, frame.w, frame.h);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, -3.0, 3.0);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        // Quake is goofy: rotate so that Z is up
        glRotatef(90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glRotatef(15.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);

        glPushMatrix();

        glRotatef(quetoo.time * 0.08, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glScalef(this->scale, this->scale, this->scale);

        glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        const r_model_t *model = R_LoadModel(this->model);
        if (model) {

            assert(model->type == MOD_MD3);

            static SDL_Texture *texture;
            if (texture == NULL) {
                const char *image = model->mesh->material->diffuse->media.name;

                SDL_Surface *surface;
                if (Img_LoadImage(image, &surface)) {
                    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
                    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
                }
            }

            assert(texture);
            SDL_GL_BindTexture(texture, NULL, NULL);

            const r_md3_t *md3 = (r_md3_t *) model->mesh->data;
            const d_md3_frame_t *frame = md3->frames;

            vec3_t verts[model->num_verts];

            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts);

            glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, model->texcoords);

            const r_md3_mesh_t *mesh = md3->meshes;
            for (uint16_t i = 0; i < md3->num_meshes; i++, mesh++) {

                const r_md3_vertex_t *v = mesh->verts;

                for (uint16_t j = 0; j < mesh->num_verts; j++, v++) {
                    VectorAdd(v->point, frame->translate, verts[j]);
                }

                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh->num_tris * 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, mesh->tris);
            }

            glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

            SDL_GL_UnbindTexture(texture);
        }

        glPopMatrix();
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, r_context.window_width, r_context.window_height);
}
```

I've debugged through the code and verified that the `SDL_Texture` object is a valid OpenGL texture. I've checked `glGetError`, and there are none. As I said, I've also tried binding the texture with:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(texnum);
```

To the same effect:

[image: The geometry is flat white]

I've read from this issue that the `SDL_Texture` will not be available for the first frame at which it is loaded:

[SDL_Renderer won't show textures after passing through the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765712/sdl-renderer-wont-show-textures-after-passing-through-the-function)

That's fine, but in my case it actually never appears. My hunch is that `SDL_Renderer` has a shader bound that does not know to sample the texture. But this is only a theory, and I'm stuck. Maybe I've missed something very simple..

Comment: You could use apitrace to write trace file and then inspect it. This will show what SDL did and what state is active at the moment of your `DrawElements`. Not sure why you want to use SDL textures for that purpose, but pure GL textures would probably give the same result as I see no obvious mistakes in given code. Are you sure your texture coordinates are correct? (data type, stride, actual values?)

Comment: Thank you for your help. As it turns out, mixing and matching the SDL_Renderer with OpenGL calls is strongly frowned upon. I was scolded in #SDL for doing so. I've gone and implemented my own small class to handle the simple 2D drawing operations I require instead. Much simpler this way.